# Error-Bundler could not find compatible versions for gem "bundler": while pushing project on Heroku

Tags: ruby-on-rails

$ git push heroku mail:master
Enter passphrase for key '/c/Users/ManishKukreja/.ssh/id_rsa':
Total 0 (delta 0), reused 0 (delta 0)

```
Heroku receiving push
Ruby/Rails app detected
Installing dependencies using Bundler version 1.1.rc.7
Heroku receiving push
Ruby/Rails app detected
```

> Installing dependencies using Bundler version 1.1.rc.7
>          Running: bundle install --without development:test --path vendor/bundle --binstubs bin/
>          Fetching gem metadata from http://rubygems.org/.......
>          Bundler could not find compatible versions for gem "bundler": 
>          In Gemfile: 
>          rails (= 3.0.1) ruby depends on 
>          bundler (~> 1.0.0) ruby 
>          Current Bundler version: 
>          bundler (1.1.rc.7) 
>          This Gemfile requires a different version of Bundler. 
>          Perhaps you need to update Bundler by running `gem install bundler`? 
>    !
>    !     Failed to install gems via Bundler.

Moreover , I already have bundler on my machine

```
Using rake (0.9.2.2)
Using activesupport (3.0.1)
Using builder (2.1.2)
Using i18n (0.4.2)
Using activemodel (3.0.1)
Using erubis (2.6.6)
Using rack (1.2.5)
Using rack-mount (0.6.14)
Using rack-test (0.5.7)
Using tzinfo (0.3.31)
Using actionpack (3.0.1)
Using mime-types (1.17.2)
Using polyglot (0.3.3)
Using treetop (1.4.10)
Using mail (2.2.19)
Using actionmailer (3.0.1)
Using bcrypt-ruby (3.0.1)
Using orm_adapter (0.0.6)
Using warden (1.1.0)
Using devise (1.5.3)
Using fastercsv (1.5.4)
Using formtastic (1.2.4)
ng fastercsv (1.5.4)
Using formtastic (1.2.4)
Using has_scope (0.5.1)
Using responders (0.6.4)
Using inherited_resources (1.2.2)
Using thor (0.14.6)
Using railties (3.0.1)
Using kaminari (0.13.0)
Using arel (1.0.1)
Using activerecord (3.0.1)
Using meta_search (0.9.8)
Using activeresource (3.0.1)
 Using bundler (1.0.10)
 Using rails (3.0.1)
 Using sass (3.1.12)
 Using activeadmin (0.3.4)
 Using addressable (2.2.6)
 Using authlogic (2.1.6)
 Using json (1.6.5)
 Using rdoc (3.12)
Using css_parser (1.2.6)
Using launchy (2.0.5)
Using rest-client (1.6.7)
Using rubyzip (0.9.5)
Using term-ansicolor (1.0.7)
Using heroku (2.18.1)
Using nokogiri (1.5.0)
Using pg (0.12.2)
Using roadie (1.1.3)


            MY GemFIle-->

            # this is test for pull and push bittu

            #require "bundler/setup"

            #gem  "rake", "0.9.2"

            source 'http://rubygems.org'

            gem 'rails', '3.0.1'

            gem 'activeadmin'

            gem 'roadie'

            gem 'heroku'

            gem 'sqlite3'

            gem 'pg'


            gem 'authlogic'
            # Bundle edge Rails instead:
            # gem 'rails', :git => 'git://github.com/rails/rails.git'

            gem 'formtastic', '~> 1.2.0'

            #gem 'mysql', '2.8.1'

            gem 'activeadmin'

            gem "mail", "2.2.19"
            #gem "rake", "0.9.2.2"

            #gem 'mail' "2.2.19"

            #gem 'pg'
            #gem 'thin'
            #gem 'sqlite3-ruby', :require => 'sqlite3'

            # gem 'mysql2'
            # gem 'mongrel'
            # Use unicorn as the web server
            # gem 'unicorn'

            # Deploy with Capistrano
            # gem 'capistrano'

            # To use debugger
            # gem 'ruby-debug'

            # Bundle the extra gems:
            # gem 'bj'
            # gem 'nokogiri'
            # gem 'sqlite3-ruby', :require => 'sqlite3'
            # gem 'aws-s3', :require => 'aws/s3'

            #gem "rspec-rails", :group => [:test, :development]

             #group :test do
              # gem "factory_girl_rails"
               #gem "guard-rspec"
               #gem "capybara"
            # end

            # Bundle gems for the local environment. Make sure to
            # put test-only gems in this group so their generators
            # and rake tasks are available in development mode:
            # group :development, :test do
            #   gem 'webrat'
            #end
```

Your bundle is complete! Use `bundle show [gemname]` to see where a bundled gem is installed.

HOw can i resolve this conflict???

Answer (score 1):

It looks like you might have Bundler set to specifically require 1.0, and Heroku's wanting to use 1.1. There would be a line in your Gemfile that reads `gem bundler, "~> 1.0"` or something similar - just knock off the comma and everything after so that it just reads `gem bundler`.

If that's not the case, can you post your Gemfile?

Comment: Hi ,THanks for the reply. My gemfile doesn't have gem bundler or anything like that-->

Comment: I have added my GEMFILE in the Question

Answer (score 1):

There are two possible ways to resolve this mentioned in this question: [Bundler could not find compatible versions for gem "bundler":](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/9854225/bundler-could-not-find-compatible-versions-for-gem-bundler)

1. Uninstall bundler 1.1.rc.7 and install bundler 1.0.22
2. Upgrade to rails 3.0.12, which supports the latest version of bundler