# heroku deployment error : bundler version

Tags: deployment, heroku

I have ruby 1.9.2 and rails 3.0.0 with bundler 1.0.22

when I push to heroku, I get

> -----> Installing dependencies using Bundler version 1.1.rc.7
>
> ```
>   Running: bundle install --without development:test --path vendor/bundle -
> ```
>
> -binstubs bin/
>
> ```
>   Fetching gem metadata from http://rubygems.org/.........
>
>   Bundler could not find compatible versions for gem "bundler":
>
>   In Gemfile:
>   rails (= 3.0.0) ruby depends on
>   bundler (~> 1.0.0) ruby
>   Current Bundler version:
>   bundler (1.1.rc.7)
>   This Gemfile requires a different version of Bundler.
>   Perhaps you need to update Bundler by running `gem install bundler`?
> ```

why does it use bundler version 1.1.rc.7 to install the dependencies and
why does it think the current bundler version is 1.1.rc.7?

No references in the .Gemfile or the Gemfile.lock to any version.

Any input appreciated.

-Thanks

Comment: please add your gemfile to the question

Comment: [this](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/8967161/error-bundler-could-not-find-compatible-versions-for-gem-bundler-while-pushin) is a very similar/duplicate question, maybe the answer helps?

Comment: I think you'll need to upgrade to Rails 3.0.3, where the bundler dependency changed from `~> 1.0.0` to `~>1.0` so 1.1 (which is in Heroku) is compatible. (The corresponding  commit is https://github.com/rails/rails/commit/8279c0652533b0d87ac58e4cbe2e84047ce97e1b)

Answer (score 0):

If you have the following lines in your Gemfile.lock:

PLATFORMS
x86-mingw32

be sure to delete them. And don't forget to use:

git add Gemfile Gemfile.lock